# Login page OR "home" page on the same URL (Laravel 5.6)

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, routes

Root page (with "/" URL) of my website should be login page (with login form) (Laravel 5 stock Auth). After user is logging in he should see his account page on the same root URL (/). How I should do it properly?

My idea is like this:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
        if (Auth::guest()) {
            return view('auth.login');
        } else {
            return view('account.index');
        }
});
```

But is is correct? It not looks like it's okay. May be I should use middleware or something else? I tried but without success.

Comment: I do not think this is a good practice. Why would you want both on the same url?

Comment: Because user can't do ANYTHING on website if he is not logged in. But it looks strange if first website page is "/login". But when he is logged in it looks strange, that first account page is "/account". And redirects, redirects everywhere.

Comment: I dont think it is strange to get redirected to a login page when you are not logged in. Maybe you can solve your problem by using Vue and the Vue router to make a SPA?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to code VUE. Anyway, thanks for helping.

Comment: VBue is the standard front end framework included with Laravel :) Maybe take a look at it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend#writing-vue-components Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can redirect you root page to login page.
The code may go like this

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        return  redirect()->route('show.login');
    } else {
        return view('account.index');
    } });
```